# Unable to create relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, relationship

All the basics are covered.

I already have a good deal of relationships in this database. However, it is silently refusing to create new relationships on tables with existing relationships.

For instance when attempting to create a relationship between FK_Scholarship and Scholarship.SCHOLARSHIP the designer becomes buggy

[image: innodb]

Equally

[image: innodb2]

Attempting to create it through the command prompt results in failure (no elaboration)

MySQL giving very little to go on to fix the issue...

Comment: Are the two types (PK and FK) exactly the same? (same type and length/precision). Can you post the table creation and constraint scripts rather than screenshots?

Comment: @Augusto they should be identical: both varchar(255).  `FK_Scholarship` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `SCHOLARSHIP` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

Comment: Do you have any other FK relationship with the same name already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit a very annoying problem. Mysql doesn't allow FKs to be set on columns larger than 255 bytes (as it cannot generate indexes for them. Varchar columns can use multiple bytes per 'character' to support UTF (some charsets have a 1-1 ratio between characters and bytes, but not all).

If you change the length to 85 it should work fine.

Another issue you might have, is that in mysql you must have an index on the FK column. If you don't create the index, mysql won't allow to FK to be created.

Comment: Okay, tried all that, but apparently no dice. Highly annoying that MySQL will not give error messages for this (makes it difficult to know if I'm getting closer to a solution!)

Comment: Deleted the database, changed the original dump going by your answer, added the constraint into the dump, and imported it and it worked. Seriously MySQL what the hell are you on?